# How to create autocomplete on click on textbox in magento2.3.5

Tags: css, jquery, magento2.3.5-p1, autocomplete, text-field

I want to create a `dynamic textbox` and using the id attribute to use `autocomplete` functionality in this. I have Developed a dynamic id for each textbox on click of add Item button and my id is provided like this `"textbox" + counter` and I want to marge text box counter as `textbox1`. So can anyone having an idea about this then please share it with me.

```
'textbox' + counter as textbox1
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: can you please add your code also in question.

Comment: I got solution of this question.